# How to design an object-database relation in Rust?

Tags: design-patterns, rust

I'm creating a Rust web application and I will need popular data types like User, Role, Privilege, etc. All of them needs to be stored in the database so for each model I need to implement an SQL query generation logic. Now I'm thinking where to put that logic in the code.

I have some ideas but all of them seem to have drawbacks.

1. Use e.g. `Create` Trait. Which then I would implement for each data type.

   ```rust
   trait Create {
       fn create(&self, client: &DbClient) -> Result<(), Error>;  
   }
   ```

   This is ok but I would like to put all the SQL logic inside a dedicated module, not tie it to data model. Also, I would have to pass `&DbClient` every time.
2. Create dedicated module e.g. `Storage` which would have `&DbClient` inside and expose an API for each concrete data type.

   ```rust
   struct Storage {
       client: &DbClient,
   }

   impl Storage {
        async fn create_user(&self, &User) -> Result<(), Error> { }
        async fn create_role(&self, &Role) -> Result<(), Error> { }
   }
   ```

   This one will result in a single struct with so many methods which I doubt is an elegant solution.
3. Create `StorageUser`, `StorageRole`, etc. but this time I would have some many generic objects to pass and it also doesn't look good for me.

   ```rust
   struct StorageUser {
       client: &DbClient,
   }

   impl StorageUser {
        async fn create(&self, &User) -> Result<(), Error> { }
   }

   struct StorageRole {
       client: &DbClient,
   }

   impl StorageRole {
        async fn create(&self, &Role) -> Result<(), Error> { }
   }
   ```

How would you approach it? I'm aware this is highly opinion-based question.

Comment: This is a fairly opinion-based question, and you might find better results asking on the Rust forums/Reddit. My two cents are to check out `diesel`. It's an ORM framework that has knowledge of your database schema, from which it can generate a type-safe query builder API.